# Rollback time for insert and delete comparison

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

With respect to Oracle RDBMS, which rollback is faster?

Rollback1 : Insert 1000000 records and then rollback

or

Rollback2 : Delete 1000000 records and then rollback

Comment: Why don't you test it? Not that I see why it matters; they're two completely different operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the % of completion of query using this:

```
SELECT SESSION_ID, percent_complete, estimated_completion_time
FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_REUQESTS
```

Comment: Does DM_EXEC_REUQESTS exist in Oracle 11g?

Comment: In case of oracle 11g,use can use LogMiner and find out the rollback transactions.

Answer (score -1):

To answer this question we should know how Oracle handles insert ande delete operations internally. I know that when you insert something, it inserts on memory, then when you commit. Oracle writes to disk.

For delete operation I found this : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_soft_logical_deletes.htm  So it logically deletes usually and when it is possible it deletes real-time.

Now we should talk about rollback, when you rollback an insert, you clear rows from memory and clear your redo logs. It sounds simple. When you rollback a delete (if Oracle deleted the rows real-time) it should go to redo log, read, then insert the deleted rows back to database.

So if I am right and logical, rollbacking a delete operation should take more time than rollbacking insert.

Also if you are deleting with condition, delete process should take more time than inserting by itself.

*P.S. Thanks for the question by the way, it's interesting and made me do some research on Oracle internals.*

Comment: @DavidAldridge thanks for comment. Also if you can explain briefly why this article is awful, I can learn something new and useful maybe.

Comment: It's a half-arsed and incomplete discussion in which he gets the suggested predicate 100% incorrect. The article he links to on optimising deletes has a number of inaccuracies, over-simplifications,  omissions etc.